# link to .exe gives 'You do not have permission to access this document' instead of downloading it

Tags: html, .htaccess

When trying to add a link to a downloadable .exe I encounter an error/notice:

'You do not have permission to access this document' instead of downloading it.

This is the anchor:

```
<a href="http://domain.nl/downloads/downloadable.exe">Here</a>
```

Using this on .zip and .dmg work fine.

I've found something eslewere, suggestion to add exe|EXE and place this in the .htaccess:

```
Deny from all 
<FilesMatch "\.(html|HTML|htm|HTM|xhtml|XHTML|js|JS|css|CSS|bmp|BMP|png|PNG|gif|GIF|jpg|JPG|jpeg|JPEG|ico|ICO|doc|DOC|docx|DOCX|txt|TXT|rtf|RTF|xls|XLS|xlsx|XLSX|csv|CSV|zip|ZIP|pdf|PDF|exe|EXE)$"> 
    Allow from all 
</FilesMatch>
```

This did not solve my problem, removing for example the PDF from this bit of code, did block the pdf download. But the other way around, adding the exe didn't enable the exe to be downloadable.

It is a WordPress install, but these downloads are not uploaded via WordPress, they are directly placed in the downloads folder.

Kind regards,

Martijn

Comment: Does the url work if you remove the .htaccess ?

Comment: I added this to the .htaccess to try out. It was not in there before and is not in there at the moment. just the plain WordPress .htaccess at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more searching, I found someone, posting a simular problem.
The suggested answer (settings with the hosting, not the actual code) there was not the solution. 
But did set us on the right path.
Previously simular code was working, but on another server, with a different config.Current domain is done via the Plesk panel.

In the Plesk panel, under the Apache & nginx settings for the domain.
Checking the box: 'Serve static files directly by nginx' solved the issue for me.